# bash not listing files in while loop

Tags: bash, sed

The below `bash` seems to run but no file names are displayed on the terminal screen, rather it just stalls.  I can not seem to figure out why it is not working now as it used to.  Thank you :).

**bash**

```
while read line; do
sed -i -e 's|https://www\.example\.com/xx/x/xxx/||'  /home/file
echo $line
done
```

**file**

```
Auto_user_xxx-39-160506_file_name_x-x_custom_xx_91-1.pdf
Auto_user_xxx-48-160601_V4-2_file_name_x-x_custom_xx_101.pdf
coverageAnalysisReport(10).zip
```

Comment: It trying to read from stdin, since you didn't redirect anything it will wait for you to type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `read` command is waiting for input, since nothing is specified it will read from stdin. If you type a few lines and press  you will see thats the input for the loop.

But you most likely want to redirect a file to the loop:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
  printf "%s\n" "$line"
done < /home/file
```

But afai can understand you have a file with other file names which you would like to run the substitution on, in that case you should use `xargs`:

```
xargs -n 1 -I {} sed -i -e 's|https://www\.example\.com/xx/x/xxx/||' {} < /home/file
```